# Copying database backup files from xamp/mysql/data of windows to linux in path /var/lib/mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-14.04

Copying database backup files from `xamp/mysql/data` of windows to linux in path `/var/lib/mysql`, but it is creating only empty database in phpmyadmin of linux.

Please some one help me to solve this issue, i have only these files backup with me

Comment: what is your database engine and how you copy data from windows to linux.

Comment: i have copied the database files in external drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is-

Step1: Take backup from windows by mysqldump-

```
mysqldump -uroot -proot123 -A > backup.sql
```

Step2: Move this backup to linux, you can use winscp tool for it.

Step3: Now restore this backup to linux machine.

```
mysql -uroot -proot123 < backup.sql
```

Modification:
It seems your db engine is myisam and you just coppied file/folder from window to linux, so give permissions as per below-

```
chown -R mysql.mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer. But i have only backup files in external drive, windows i uninstalled

Comment: what was your db engine innodb or myisam and in which format you have your backup in external drive.

Comment: apache2 phpmyadmin. database folders are there in that table files in different extentions like .frm .MYD .TRG

Comment: it is showingERROR: Can't initialize batch_readline - may be the input source is a directory or a block device.

Comment: for this you need to go to linux server and then execute this command from linux prompt not mysql prompt.

Comment: these database folders are not in .sql format, these are normal folders

Comment: am executing in linux prompt bhai, please help me i dont have any other way to recover databases

Comment: are you checking on linux at /var/lib/mysql folder and getting your db here and .frm/.myi/.myd etc file in db folder....

Comment: yes  i have stored all databases in /var/lib/mysql folder but it is showing only database names in phpmyadmin not tables

Comment: dear Zub, I can help you only if you listen me...I am saying to connect linux server and check if /var/lib/mysql contains your datbases and database folder contains files like .myi, .myd, .frm etc...

Comment: i have installed apache in my local system. which linux server u r telling i dint get u

Comment: i used this command to start server  sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

First create a `.my.cnf` file containing the mysql root password in your users home folder, on linux.
On windows, there exists a `.my.ini` or something which serves the same purpose. That way you will not have to reenter your passwords a lot during the next steps, which you are very likely to repeat several times until you get them right, I fear. :)

Since unix/linux and windows have different ways to save files, you might very likely run into errors during a simple copy-restore process, depending on how you copy files.

Your best bet is likely copying the original `mysql` folders to another windows machine and save them accordingly, such that `mysql` can find them. (With an installed `mysql` instance, of course.) I don't know what else you might need, if the databases are not found instantly, since I never had to do this prior and have no test setup here to check this case out.

When the databases are found through the `mysql` on the WINDOWS server, from the `mysql` cli prompt there look up which encoding etc the db uses:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME 'database', default_character_set_name 'charset', DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME 'collation' FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA;
```

Then create a new database on the LINUX server with the same name and the same encoding's from MYSQL CLI:

```
create database <db-name> character set <charset> collate <collation>;
```

Then on the WINDOWS server in a CMD window, do a `mysqldump` which should look familiar on windows like on linux:

```
mysqldump  <db-name>  >  <db-name>.sql
```

Then copy the dump over to the LINUX server and replay it:

```
mysql  <db-name>  <  <db-name>.sql
```

Afterwards you will have to recreate a user (if you know which user and password your web app used to access the database, create a new user with these credentials and grant him full access on your database.

If you do not happen to know the credentials anymore, create an arbitrary user and then change the database credentials in the configfile of your web application.

In case you have problems, check the unix file permissions of the files you copied, such that mysql can access them.

Good luck, mate.